# Which C++ feature ensures fool-proof extracting T& from optional<T>?

Tags: c++, option-type, language-design

To be fool-proof, it needs:

- clean syntax
- possibility to use `auto`
- atomic usage, to prevent accidental mistakes like `if (!opt) { opt->call(); }`
- no run-time assertions (**EDIT**: and exceptions)
- no compiler warnings
- (optional) no static checker warnings

So far I've tried these 4 options (assume having a variable `optional<T> opt;`):

**Option 0.** Standard usage

```
if (opt) {
    opt->call();
}
```

- **+** Clean code
- **+** Natural control flow, having `else` statement
- **-** Not atomic
- **-** `operator->` is exposed in a nullable type, so it's easy to call `opt->call()` without `if` check

**Option 1.** Create a smart pointer `almost_present<T>` with `_DEBUG`-only field `mutable boolean checkedPresent` that is set to `true` when user does `operator bool`:

```
if (almost_present<T> nonull = opt.if_present()) {
    // `operator->()` and `operator T&()` assert if called without doing `if (nonull)`
    nonull->call();
    T& x = nonull;
}
```

- **+** Natural control flow, having `else` statement
- **+** Will assert if user doesn't check value before referencing, even if it's present
- **-** Run-time checks
- **-** `almost_present<T>::operator bool() const` has to modify `checkedPresent` field
- **-** May accidentally use `nonull` in the `else` branch, but that's minor

**Option 2.** Range-based for loop trick from http://loungecpp.net/cpp/abusing-range-for/ : `optional<T>` or `optional<T>::if_present()` implements methods `begin()` and `end()` to look like a collection of 0 or 1 items

```
for (auto& nonull : opt.if_present()) {
    nonull.call();
}
```

- **+** Clean syntax
- **-** Unconditional `return` inside any loop produces `warning C4702: unrechable code` (VC2017)
- **-** No `else` statement, have to call `if (!opt)` separately, and that's not atomic
- **-** Looks like a loop, may be misinterpret if `T` is a collection

**Option 3.** Lambdas

```
opt.if_present([](auto& nonull) { nonull.call(); });
auto result = opt.map(
        [](auto& nonull) { return nonull.call(); },
        []() { return what_if_null(); }
    );
```

- **+** it works
- **-** not a clean syntax - hard to read and debug

For now, I use a combination of "for" loop and "lambdas"

Comment: Almost present looks like optional to me.

Comment: I wouldn't use .2 and .3 for anything other than amusement. That kind of code is effectively confusing.

Comment: @Yakk, `almost_present` preventively asserts if you forgot to `if`, so it's enough to cover this code with 1 test. And `std::optional<T>` will fail only when you pass an empty value, which could be very rare.

Comment: @MykolaBogdiuk Why not have that on an optional?  It is equally bad.  Strip it in release builds natch

Comment: @Yakk, I prefer separating nullable classes from non-nullable, and it's safer for nullable classes to not expose operators `->`  and `*`. Actually, I found a hidden bug in a small codebase when migrated code from Option0 to Option2, so it proves to be useful.

Comment: @Yakk, that's why I'm asking - Option0 looks clean, Option2 and 3 are safe, but I can't think of something that looks clean and is safe at the same time

Comment: The trick is to treat optional like a container/range that can hold 0 or 1 values and then write an iterator for it. That makes it available to C++ range based for loops and possibly the rangev3 operators.

Answer (score 1):

This is relatively easy once you consider that optional is a container that can hold 0 or 1 elements. All you need is an iterator for optional. Pity it doesn't come in the standard library but it is easy to construct it.

https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8a63a12f31735b1b

for a running example. The source code is below.

We create an input iterator for optional that holds a pointer to the original optional. An end iterator holds a nullptr.

```
#include <optional>

template <typename T>
struct OptionalIterator 
{
    using iterator_category = std::forward_iterator_tag;
    using difference_type   = std::ptrdiff_t;
    using value_type        = T;
    using pointer           = T*;  // or also value_type*
    using reference         = T&;  // or also value_type&
    
    OptionalIterator(std::optional<T> & opt):m_ptr(opt?&opt:nullptr){}
    OptionalIterator():m_ptr(nullptr){};
    
    using Iterator = OptionalIterator<T>;
    
    reference operator*() const { return **m_ptr; }
    pointer operator->() { return &**m_ptr; }

    // Prefix increment
    Iterator & operator++() { m_ptr=nullptr; return *this; }  

    // Postfix increment
    Iterator operator++(int) { Iterator tmp = *this; ++(*this); return tmp; }

    friend bool operator== (const Iterator& a, const Iterator& b) { 
        return a.m_ptr == b.m_ptr; 
    };
    
    friend bool operator!= (const Iterator& a, const Iterator& b) {
        return !(a==b); 
    };  
    
    private:
    std::optional<T> * m_ptr;
};

namespace std {
template <typename T> 
OptionalIterator<T> 
begin(std::optional<T> & opt){
    return OptionalIterator<T>(opt);
}

template <typename T> 
OptionalIterator<T> 
end(std::optional<T> & ){
    return OptionalIterator<T>();
}
}
```

We can test it with

```
#include <iostream>


int main(){
    std::optional<int> a(10),b(std::nullopt);
    std::cerr << "a" << std::endl;
    for(auto v: a){
        std::cerr << v << std::endl;
    }
    std::cerr << "b" << std::endl;

    for(auto v: b){
        std::cerr << v << std::endl;
    }
}
```

which outputs

```
a
10
b
```

In summary, instead of doing

```
if(foo){
  std::cerr << *foo ;
}
```

you do

```
for(auto v : foo){
   std::cerr << v;
}
```

The added benefit is that it should work with all the range operators with range V3 but I haven't tried it.

Comment: Thank you. I use this approach currently (see "Option 2" from the question). Main problems: cannot `else` atomically and ending a simple function `for (auto& v : opt) { return v->count; } return 0;` produces a warning about unreachable statement (implicit `++iterator`)

Comment: There are other ways to do that. I'll get back to you.

Comment: In this case you should use a combination of map and default combinators. The code would look a bit like ”opt | map([](auto val){return v->count;}) | else([](){return 0;})" Requires quite a bit of framework code to achieve the piping operations but have a look at rangev3 for inspiration.

Answer (score -1):

```
auto v = opt.value();
```

Throws a [`bad_optional_access`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional/bad_optional_access) if `opt` contains no value.

Comment: Well, that's what I'm trying to avoid - runtime asserts and throws

Comment: @MykolaBogdiuk You didn't mention that you wanted to avoid exceptions.

Comment: Formally yes, but I wouldn't use `optional<T>` if I definitely knew it's not empty in the first place. Will edit the question.